# Implement custom interface in RecyclerViewAdapter with Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView Implemented in my app. i want to change, add and remove items remotely with notifyItemRemoved and notifyItemChanged and not with setDataChange due to performance difference. i want to make some interface objects i guess but i coudn't figured it out how or where to implement and override inteface method, ect.

this is my implementation of RecyclerView in MainActivity.kt

```
val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    adapter = RecyclerAdapter(itemList)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

this is my Interface:

```
public interface AddItemListener {
    void addItem(int position);
}
```

and this is my RecyclerView class with its ViewHolder:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val items: ArrayList<RecyclerViewListModel>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false))

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.onBind()
    }


    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun onBind(){}
    }

}
```

i have Floating button in MainActivity. i want to have access Viewholder in order to add element. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener to your adapter like this:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val items: ArrayList<RecyclerViewListModel>, internal var listener: AddItemListener) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
    MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false))

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind()
}

fun addNewItem(item : RecyclerViewListModel){
   items.add(item)
   notifyItemInserted(items.size - 1)
}

fun removeItem(position : Int){
   items.removeAt(position)
   notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
    View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        listener. addItem(adapterPosition)
    }

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    fun onBind(){}
  }
}
```

add click listener in your activity/fragment:

```
adapter = RecyclerAdapter(itemList, this)
```

implement AddItemListener fun:

```
override fun addItem(int position){
   // you can get item click position
   // you can show the dialog as like "Do you want to delete?"
   adapter.romoveItem(position) 
}
```

add new item:

```
val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
     adapter.addNewItem(RecyclerViewListModel(verb1, verb2....))
}
```

Comment: You don't need an interface to add a new item. This interface helps to access the item of recyclerView. For example you can use to remove item or other process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. if we concern the fun addItem for the removal of the item, i dont get what should i write in function in order to delete element from list and call notify method

Comment: I edited my answer. You can change interface name. I used your interface to remove item.